# Не выдает четырехзначное число без одинаковых цифр

Tags: python

```
a = int(random.uniform(1, 9))
b = int(random.uniform(0, 9))
c = int(random.uniform(0, 9))
d = int(random.uniform(0, 9))

while nig < 10:
    `while b == a:
        b = int(random.uniform(0, 9))

    while c == a and c == b:
        c = int(random.uniform(0, 9))

    while d == a and d == c and d == b:
        d = int(random.uniform(0, 9))`





    number_sof_comp = str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d)
    print(number_sof_comp)
    nig = nig+1
```

Эта программа должна выдавать число без повторяющихся цифр, например 3456, 9748
пример как не должно быть 3445, 7897.
Она выдает просто случайное число.

Comment: это можно легко решить с помощью `random.sample`

Answer (score 0):

создание переменных надо занести в цикл. Также в `while` `and` надо поменять на `or`. И место `uniform` лучше использовать `randrange`

```
import random


nig = 0

while nig < 10:
    a = random.randrange(1, 10)
    b = random.randrange(10)
    c = random.randrange(10)
    d = random.randrange(10)
    
    while b == a:
        b = random.randrange(10)

    while c == a or c == b:
        c = random.randrange(10)
        
    while d == a or d == c or d == b:
        d = random.randrange(10)
    
    number_sof_comp = str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d)
    print(number_sof_comp)
    nig = nig+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно использовать `itertools.permutations`:

```py
from itertools import permutations

numbers = []
digits = 4

for tup in permutations(map(str, range(10)), 4):
    if tup[0] == '0':
        continue
    print(tup)
    numbers.append(int(''.join(tup)))
```